# Java List<> of another Pojo object not getting initialised

Tags: java, json, pojo, fasterxml

I have a Pojo class in which I have the following field : And when I am passing the date, it shows null.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
public class ParentPojo {

@JsonProperty("ChildPojoExample")
private List<ChildPojo> child;

public List<ChildPojo> getChild() {
    return child;
}

public void setChild(List<ChildPojo> child) {
    this.child= child;
}

public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("ParentPojo [ChildPojo=");
        builder.append(child);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
}



public class ChildPojo{

    private String First;

    private String Second;

    private Double Third;

    public String getFirst() {
        return First;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first) {
        First= first;
    }

    public String getSecond() {
        return Second;
    }

    public void setSecond(String second) {
        Second= second;
    }

    public Double getThird() {
        return Third;
    }

    public void setThird(Double third) {
        Third= third;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("ChildPojo [First=");
        builder.append(First);
        builder.append(", Second=");
        builder.append(Second);
        builder.append(", Third=");
        builder.append(Third);
        builder.append("]");
        return builder.toString();
    }

}
```

Request :

```
{
"ChildPojoExample": [{
"First": "test1",
"Second": "test2",
"Third": 0.024
 }]
}
```

I am getting following as the Request Pojo object :

```
ParentPojo =[ChildPojo [First=null, Second=null, Third=null]]
```

I am not able to figure out why the values are not coming in the object correctly, instead null is coming.

I am converting the request following way :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/APIName")
    @ResponseBody
    public Response methodName(@RequestBody ParentPojo request) throws IOException {
        Loggers..info("ParentPojo request : {}  ", request);
}
```

Comment: You've shown the creation of the POJO, but we don't know how it's being deserialized. What is receiving this request, exactly? Are you able to provide a [mcve] which performs the deserialization explicitly?

Comment: Show how you are converting the request-response into objects. basically your fasterxml conversion

Comment: @JonSkeet provided the missing part

Comment: @RajnishMishra provided the missing part

Comment: That's a very long way from a [mcve]. Again, if you could show a concrete example of the deserialization (rather than just a method declaration from somewhere in a server using libraries you haven't told us about) that would make it much easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the case of the variable names in the `ChildPojo` class. It expects the variable names to start with lower case letters

You can use the `JsonProperty` annotation to fix it.

```
@JsonProperty("First")
private String First;

@JsonProperty("Second")
private String Second;

@JsonProperty("Third")
private Double Third;
```